# Spring Data Neo4j Repository Save method is doing UNWIND MATCH instread of UNWIND CREATE

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

**Please find the below classes for spring data neo4j rest example**

**Model Class**

```
@Data
@NodeEntity
public class Model implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   private String uUID;

   private boolean status = true;

   @CreatedDate
   private Date createdDate;

   @LastModifiedDate
   private Date modifiedDate;

}
```

**ModelRepository Class**

```
@Repository
public interface ModelRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Model, Long> {

   Optional<Model> findByStatusTrueAndUUID(UUID uuid);

   Stream<Model> streamAllByStatusTrue();
}
```

**Service Class Method**

```
public Model createModel(Model request) throws DSException {
      return modelRepository.save(request);
}
```

Repository.save method generated the below cypher query

```
UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n)=row.nodeId SET n:`Model` SET n += row.props RETURN row.nodeId as ref, ID(n) as id, {type} as type with params {type=node, rows=[{nodeId=1, props={createdDate=null, name=1-name, modifiedDate=2019-02-26T12:05:16.184Z, uUID=05fdb066-13a4-4ed2-b53f-f3e48b5ff9ba, status=true}}]}
```

Because of the above cypher query which have `MATCH` instead of `CREATE`, the request node is not persisting in the neo4j database

Please help in understanding and solving the issue.
Below are versions used:

```
spring-data-neo4j:5.0.7.RELEASE
```

Comment: Please can you confirm that the `id` property is null when you save the Model. If it is not null, SDN will expect the entity to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the type of the property added. If you wont pass the right property type like string or integer as provided by the `@NodeEntity`, we encounter this error

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.
Finally I found if you assigned the id property for Model the Neo4j Repository Save method is doing UNWIND MATCH instead of UNWIND CREATE;
If you didn't assign the id, then the Neo4j Repository  Save method is doing UNWIND CREATE.